# Angular and RxJS: Handling a Product Detail Page Refresh with URL Parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm working on an Angular application where I have a product detail page that uses a URL parameter (e.g., /products/product;id=2) to select a specific product to display. I'm using RxJS for managing the data flow (it works well when the app as previously fetched the products list).

I have a selectedProductIdSubject BehaviorSubject to store the selected product ID. However, I've encountered an issue when refreshing the page, the selected product is not displayd. The problem is that when I refresh the page, the selectedProductIdSubject is re-initialized to null, and when I try to combine it with the this.products$ observable, it initially emits with a non-null selectedProductId (ex: id=2) and an empty products array, then when products$ finally emits when products list the selectedProductId emits null

Here is the code:

ProductsService.ts

```
private selectedProductIdSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number | null>(null);
selectedProductId$ = this.selectedProductIdSubject.asObservable();

readonly selectedProduct$ = combineLatest([this.products$, this.selectedProductId$]).pipe(
    map(([products, selectedProductId]) => {
        return products.find((r: ProductDTO) => r.id == selectedProductId) ?? null;
    })
);

...

setSelectedProductId(id: number | null) {
    this.selectedProductIdSubject.next(id);
}
```

ProductDetailComponent

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const productId = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')) ?? -1;
    this.productsService.setSelectedProductId(productId);
}
```

**Debug calls**:

- page refresh when URL: "/products/product;id=2"

1. setSelectedProductId(2)
2. combineLatest -> products$: [], selectedProductId$: 2
3. combineLatest -> products$: [Product(), Product(), ...], selectedProductId$: null

I've tried using withLatestFrom to wait for both the selectedProductId and products to be available before emitting a value, but the issue persists.

How can I ensure that when the products$ finally emits when fetched list the selectedProductId keeps returning the current route id?

Any guidance on how to handle this situation gracefully would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show how you've defined the route for the `/products/product` path. Also, is there any other invocation of the `setSelectedProductId` method in `ProductsService`?

Answer (score -1):

Use a `Subject` instead of `BehaviourSubject`. Simple `Subject` does not return an initial value.

Use `filter` operator to ensure that `products` is not empty.

```
readonly selectedProduct$ = combineLatest([this.products$, this.selectedProductId$]).pipe(
    filter([products, selectedProductId] => products.length),
    map(([products, selectedProductId]) => {
        return products.find((r: ProductDTO) => r.id == selectedProductId) ?? null;
    })
);
```

Comment: You're confusing the two kinds of Subjects. Its Subject that does not return an initial value.

Comment: I wrote `Subject` does not return an initial value?